# KnockoutJS Binding More Than Once Per Document

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

In KnockoutJS if you have an external template you need to wait until it loads to apply your `ViewModel` bindings. That means that if the external template doesn't load then nothing in my page will be binded to knockout. Is there a way to separate bindings, one for the external template and one for the other content in the page?

P.S. I know I can apply `ko.bindings` even if the template doesn't load, but the rest of the page is still waiting to get its bindings while the external template loads!

Please help. All answers appreciated.

**Pseudocode:**

1. get external template full of html and ko bindings
2. if template loaded, THEN apply `ViewModel` bindings
3. if template doesn't load, apply no bindings
4. other bindings in the page, not from the external template, will not
   be binded.

Comment: Add fiddle or some code so that your question will become more clear.

Comment: @dnyanesh See my edit for some pseudocode, thanks.

Comment: Call `ko.applyBindings(viewModel, templateContainerElement)` on template loaded callback.

Comment: Does that mean I can apply bindings to everything else like so: `ko.applyBindings(App); and then ko.applyBindings(viewModel, templateContainerElement);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can apply ko.appybinding() as my times as you want to apply.

If look at it, it is actually `applyBindings(object model, HtmlElement rootElement)`. So what it means it you can give any root element and your model and it is knockout's job to apply those bindings.

Coming back to your question.

1. Get the external  with ko bindings
2. If your template is loaded find the root element and call ko.applyBindings(newModel, newlyLoadedElemnt)